# Как применить метод .filter на объектах из массива через функцию?

Tags: javascript, filter

Есть массив с объектами, и мне нужно фильтровать объекты число которых выше N числа, код примерно такой:

Массив:

```
const actors = [
  {
    name: `Paul`,
    age: 24,
  },
  {
    name: `Sheyla`,
    age: 22,
  },
  {
    name: `John`,
    score: 18,
  }
```

Пример кода:

```
const topScoreFilter = (show) => {
  const score = shows.filter((score) => score > 90);
  console.log(score)
};

shows.filter(topScoreFilter);
```

Но при попытке запустить, выдает "show.filter() is not a function", гуглил, так и не понял как использовать этот метод на объектах в массивах.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const actors = [
  {
    name: `Paul`,
    age: 24
  },
  {
    name: `Sheyla`,
    age: 22
  },
  {
    name: `John`,
    age: 18
  }
];

const topAgeFilter = a => a.age > 20;

console.log(actors.filter(topAgeFilter));
```